# JavaScript regex with back reference

Tags: regex

I would like to construct regex (in JavaScript) that would return:

- for string "test" groups (test) and ()   *second group being empty*
- and for string "test-a" groups (test) and (test-a)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done with:

```
/(?=(test))(test-a)?/
```

Replace `test` and `a` with the pattern you are really looking for.

You may also want to anchor it, eg:

```
/^(?=(test))(?=(test-a)?)test(?:-a)?$/
```